# video card performance monitoring?

Tags: linux, performance, graphics-card, monitoring

Is there a 'top' like command for monitoring the GPU and memory usage of a video card?  I am most interested in Linux commands, but and OS would be interesting.

I strongly suspect that for a group of my systems the video cards are being under-utilized (but I have no idea by how much) and would like to re-allocate funds to other bottle-necks.  We are using higher end cards, so the price difference between cards is significant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a nVidia card, then the **[RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner)** is your best bet. You can monitor the graphics memory and processor clock speeds, you can overclock your gfx card, customize DirectX, OpenGL and more.

> RivaTuner is a complete powerful
>   tweaking environment, providing you
>   everything you may need to tune NVIDIA
>   GPU based display adapters. The widest
>   driver-level Direct3D / OpenGL and
>   system tuning options, flexible
>   profiling system allowing to make
>   custom settings on per-application
>   basis, both driver-level and low-level
>   hardware access modes, unique
>   diagnostic and **realtime hardware
>   monitoring features**.

nVidia also offer their own tools:

> **[NVIDIA PerfHUD](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nvperfhud_home.html)** is a powerful real-time performance analysis tool
>   for Direct3D applications. PerfHUD is
>   widely used by the world's best game
>   developers and was a 2007 Game
>   Developer Magazine Frontline Award
>   Finalist.

and this one is available for Windows and Linux:

> **[NVIDIA PerfKit](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nvperfkit_home.html)** is a comprehensive suite of performance
>   tools to help debug and profile OpenGL
>   and Direct3D applications.
>
> It gives you access to low-level
>   performance counters inside the driver
>   and hardware counters inside the GPU
>   itself. The counters can be used to
>   determine exactly how your application
>   is using the GPU

Comment: Thank you.  PerfKit looks like it may do what I want with its gpu_idle counter.

Comment: you're most welcome.